# Invalid utf8 character string on mysqldump script

Tags: mysql, flyway, mysql-5.5

I've created a copy of a database and changed the collation and charset to `utf8mb4` (originally it was `latin1`), then used `mysqldump` to create a script for a `Flyway` database migration.

When I run the following script

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.62, for Win64 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: feedback
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.15

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `COMPONENT_GROUP`
--

LOCK TABLES `COMPONENT_GROUP` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `COMPONENT_GROUP` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `COMPONENT_GROUP` VALUES ('AAAB','AAA - MOTOR','LUBRIFICAÇÃO DO MOTOR','LUBRIFICAÇÃO DO MOTOR',NULL,NULL,20181219,1)
UNLOCK TABLES;


/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-05-22 13:07:38
```

flyway shows messages like these:

```
WARNING: DB: Invalid utf8 character string: 'C7C34F' (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 1300)
WARNING: DB: Incorrect string value: '\xC3O FUN...' for column 'claimed_name_pt' at row 10 (SQL State: HY000 - Error Code: 1366)
```

When I run the dump script using tools like SQLyog and MySQL Workbench the data is correctly inserted, so how can I fix that for Flyway?

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, could you change "VALUES ('AAAB','AAA - MOTOR','LUBRIFICAÇÃO DO MOTOR','LUBRIFICAÇÃO DO MOTOR',NULL,NULL,20181219,1)" to "VALUES ('AAAB','AAA - MOTOR','LUBRIFICACAO DO MOTOR','LUBRIFICACAO DO MOTOR',NULL,NULL,20181219,1)" just as a test to see if the accented characters are causing the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of Flyway are you using ? Please take a look at this closed [issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2200) if you haven't done it yet.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the missing part to fix the migration issue. I had to add encoding settings to the Flyway's connection string:

```
FLYWAY_URL="jdbc:mysql://${db_instance.default.address}:3306/${mysql_database.db-app.name}?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true"
```